# How do I see the value of a string stored in a private variable?

Tags: privacy, state-variable

I have read many times that sensitive data should never be stored in a transaction, but, specifically, how would the value of a state variable be read if marked `private`?

Comment: From Solidity, you can not read private variables. For direct access of storage, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/how-to-read-a-private-variable-from-a-contract

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the example contract you gave, it looks like there's a `bytes32` state variable at slot 1 with the value "A very strong secret password :)".

I found this by just calling `getStorageAt` a couple times:

```
> web3.eth.getStorageAt('0x6260319bcbcbf33f84397ae0000e49b0f50ee075', 0, (e, v) => console.log(v))
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
> web3.eth.getStorageAt('0x6260319bcbcbf33f84397ae0000e49b0f50ee075', 1, (e, v) => console.log(v))
0x412076657279207374726f6e67207365637265742070617373776f7264203a29
> web3.eth.getStorageAt('0x6260319bcbcbf33f84397ae0000e49b0f50ee075', 1, (e, v) => console.log(web3.toAscii(v)));
A very strong secret password :)
```

If we had the source code for the contract, this would be much easier. And if the contract were obfuscated, this would be somewhat harder.

But the bottom line is that everything on the blockchain (including private state variables) is public.

Comment: Interesting. Nice work!

Comment: @smarx do the `>` marks indicate you're using geth for that? I can't get an attached console session to take js (coffeescript?) like that

Comment: I was doing this in Chrome. Not sure what version of JavaScript `geth` supports, but it probably doesn't like the lambda syntax. In `geth`, no need for a callback anyway. Just `web3.eth.getStorageAt('<address>', 1)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Any contract code deployed to the blockchain can be read/viewed by anyone. This includes variables/functions declared `private` The only thing `private` does is restrict access of that variable/function to the contract it is declared within.

From the docs:[image]

Comment: My question is asking for someone to show the steps for viewing the an arbitrary state variable marked `private`.

Comment: In this case, you would need to view the contract code/ABI on etherscan, and determine the value of the variable on your own.

Comment: So for example, https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6260319bcbcbf33f84397ae0000e49b0f50ee075#code if there's no ABI shown, the string data is not readable?

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-can-you-decompile-a-smart-contract. 
With no contract code/ABI, I don't believe it is possible to recover specific values using only opcodes/bytecode (especially if the code was compiled using the optimizer).

Comment: It is of course _possible_, though the difficulty goes up. (See my answer for how easy this particular contract is.)