# Hide the value of a variable until a condition is fulfilled

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, privacy, zero-knowledge

Let's say i have a variable, whose value is set by a user calling a certain method

```
string commitment;

function setValue(x) public
    {
        commitment = x;
    }
```

if I want to hide the value of this 'commitment' variable from **all other parties interacting the contract**, until a certain condition is fulfilled, is it possible to do this in Solidity?

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible, even if you declare private variables since you can still read it using the opcode `getStorageAt`

This was answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/44897/99976)